# Is there a way to have to ion-buttons side by side with an angle between them?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Kia Ora, I am trying to put two buttons side by side with an angle between them as demonstrated in the picture below, but I am struggling to even have the two buttons side by side with full length even with out an angle, and i am unsure if its even possible?

here is my current code that uses and ion-grid, but they just appear as two buttons side by side not at full length, i figured if the expand property is set to full then this should be at full length?

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-6>
    <ion-button  expand="full" share="round" color="light">settings</ion-button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-6>
    <ion-button  expand="full" share="round" color="gold">edit profile</ion-button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxV04.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `expand="full"` is for Ionic 4/5, but you're using Ionic 3 (according to the tag of the question).

In Ionic 3 you should use the `full` attribute instead:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#full-buttons

```
<button ion-button full>Full Button</button>
```

Please also notice that the right *component* is `<button ion-button>...</button>`, and not `<ion-button>...</ion-button>` since that's also for Ionic 4/5.